# CDO.Message Email from Office 365 Account in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, email, ms-access, cdo.message

I'm trying to send an email from an account on Office 355 using CDO.message in VBA to automate some email tasks in Microsoft Access.

The code is from [this](https://www.tachytelic.net/2018/12/email-vbscript-vba-office-365/) source.

I get

> "The transport failed to connect to the server"

From my research, it seems to be an issue with TLS authentication.

```vb
Dim objMessage, objConfig, fields
Set objMessage = New CDO.message
Set objConfig = New CDO.Configuration
Set fields = objConfig.fields
With fields
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.office365.com"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 '465
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "noreply@domain.ca"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "passowrd"
    '.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendtls") = True
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
    .Update
End With
Set objMessage.Configuration = objConfig
    
With objMessage
    .subject = "Test Message"
    .From = "noreply@domain.ca"
    .To = "noreply@domain.ca"
    .HTMLBody = "Test Message"
End With
objMessage.Send
```

EDIT: The email needs to be sent from the same email address no matter the user, and thus, I don't believe using Outlook will work.

EDIT 2: It seems to be that ports 25 and 465 are blocked by my ISP. Using telnet I was able to get a response from port 587, however, I get the same error as before (except this time I get it immediately instead of after a long delay). Likely due to lack of TLS authentication.

Comment: smtpserverport 25? Most ISPs block that.

Comment: @StureS do you have a suggest for what port to use? I tried  port 465 (Found that suggestion online) and I get the same error.

Comment: Try 587 with TLS

Comment: @StureS WIth 587 and TLS I get the error "The server rejected the sender address... STARTTLS is required to send mail'

Comment: You have a problem with login procedures. It's logical.
You are actually stating that you want to send an email from one person, no matter who the actual sender is. That's how spam works and will not be allowed.

Comment: @StureS I see your point but I'm surprised that there doesn't seem to be a way to send emails in VBA from one account. I'm not very familiar with email procedures. I had a noreply@company.com office 365 account setup with the thinking that I could do as I've tried above. Would the correct way of doing this be to setup a distribution group "noreply" with everyone in the company having permissions for send as / send on behalf of and then using the Outlook VBA reference with SentOnBehalfOfName?

Comment: Probably. You definitely need permission to send as another, That's the basic rule.

Comment: We use a shared mailbox for this. Then delegate this to the relevant users.

Answer (score 2):

This is an alternative that I've used before:

```
Private Sub btnSendEmail_Click()
    Dim olObject As Object
    Dim mail As Object
    Dim address As String, subject As String, body As String
    
    Set olObject = New Outlook.Application
    Set mail = olObject.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    address = "fakeemail@test.com"
    subject = "THIS IS THE EMAILS SUBJECT LINE"
    body = "THIS GOES INTO EMAILS MESSAGE BODY"
    
    mail.To = address
    mail.subject = subject
    mail.HTMLBody = body
    mail.Send
    
    If MsgBox("Email Sent!", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Submitted") = vbOK Then: Exit Sub
End Sub
```

And here are the required references:
[vba references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUmEp.png)

I've used this from a MS Access form where the user enters text that goes into the message, then clicks a "Send Email" button to send via Outlook. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately I need the email to be sent from the same email no matter which user is using the application. Using Outlook requires the user to be logged into the account already. As far as I'm aware CDO.message is the only method for my needs.

Comment: You are actually stating that you want to send an email from one person, no matter who the actual sender is. That's how spam works and will not be allowed.

Answer (score -1):

Your settings are correct.

What you miss is, most likely, to create and use an *App Password*.

Official documentation:

[Manage app passwords for two-step verification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/user-help/multi-factor-authentication-end-user-app-passwords?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361)

As a very first step, open a command prompt and verify you can reach the server:

```
telnet smtp.office365.com 25
```

This shall at once return something like this:

```
220 HE1PR09CA0075.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Fri, 19 Feb 2021 18:48:46 +0000
```

If that times out, check your firewall and router settings.

Comment: Hmm. I don't have to 2FA on this account. Do you still think an app password is the problem?

Comment: Perhaps not, but try the initial check - see extended answer, please.

Comment: It times out with 25 and 465. I get a response using port 587, however, I still get "the transport failed to connect to the server" when using that port in MS-Access.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Would a better option be to setup a distribution group "noreply" and have everyone in the company have send as /send on behalf of permissions and then use the Outlook reference to send the emails using .SentOnBehalfOfName?

Comment: Is noreply@domain.ca a real e-mail account? If so, it has to work using this for login and as sender. Until that works, it makes no sense to try to send on behalf of other users.